# Using counter or constant for parameter position

Tags: java, optimization, readability

Suppose that I have the following Java code:

```
int i = 0;

PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table " +   
"WHERE field1 = ?, field2 = ?, field3 = ?...");

statement.set***(++i, fieldValue);
```

And there are like 14 fields like that.

Then we have another prepared statement, but this time we see this:

```
i = 0;
PreparedStatement otherPreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table " +   
    "WHERE field1 = ?, field2 = ?, field3 = ?...")

statement.set***(++i, fieldValue);
```

**All of this in the same method.**

We flagged this as error prone and we recommended that we should be using constants like this:

```
preparedStatement.set***(PARAMETER_X_INDEX, fieldValue);
```

Now, I know that having these many parameters is just bad, but I do not see a way to refactor to use less.

What observations can be said about the first code and about the recommendation?

Comment: Why use a prepared statement if you are not going to take advantage of the ability to bind (and rebind) parameters? Also, [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @Snowman what do you mean by bind/rebind parameters?

Comment: The point of a prepared statement is that it is possible to bind parameters via `?` and those `setXYZ()` methods, compile and execute the statement, then bind _different_ parameters and execute without recompiling the statement. Declaring the same prepared statement twice in the same scope shows a lack of understanding of JDBC.

Comment: @ElderMael Most databases will provide methods that bind parameter names directly to objects in your programming language, so you can just write the parameter names in your query and let the database engine take care of the error-prone string substitution/escaping issues for you. Usually it's as simple as `dbService.bindInteger('field1', 42)`

Comment: @Snowman is that available in plain JDBC (and we are also stuck on Java 6)

Comment: @Ixrec see my previous comment

Comment: @ElderMael I am not sure exactly how long [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) has been in core Java but some of its methods were added in Java 1.2, implying the class has been around for a _very_ long time. Also, your Java 6 code in the question uses it.

Comment: @Snowman I just checked the PreparedStatement API and I do not see a way to bind parameters by name.

Comment: @ElderMael I am not sure why binding by name is relevant, looking at the code in the question. The only way to access SQL elements by name is when looking at a `ResultSet`.

Comment: @Snowman that is the whole point of the code review, we are saying that using the counter is error prone. I am not talking about getting SQL fields using the ResultSet, but about setting parameters to a PreparedStatement.

Comment: @ElderMael I was simply referring to accessing them "by name" which is meaningless. Maybe "by named constant" would be more accurate. Still, this is essentially a code review which is not really on-topic here anyway. Yes, the code is bad. Yes, it can be improved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36719/discussion-between-snowman-and-eldermael).